# How to save responses in Visual Studio Code ThunderClient?

Tags: visual-studio-code, thunderclient

I want to keep responses to examine later, when I dont have VPN connection or my local environment is not running.

I saw that the response mesages are gone after restarting VS code.

Does this tool have this functionality?

If I have to save the info i need to a text file, then I have no reason to use this tool? I could just save curl requests...